SE-like forums focussed on neuropsychology
I am desperately looking for an SE-like forum with a stronger focus on neuropsychology, i.e. in comparably equal parts with neurosciences and psychology (both cognitive and beyond).
Answers outside the SE-ecosystem are welcome.

Although your question is implied, it would help phrasing it explicitely.

Welcome! Perhaps you need not search longer. We welcome questions on neuropsychology on the main site!
Being a site that welcomes these types of questions, we would obviously not encourage you finding other places to submit them.

Among 4,600 questions there are only 10 tagged with "neuropsychology". This makes me a little bit... nervous.

True. However, 466 are tagged [tag:neurobiology] (a tag synonym on this site of [tag:neuroscience]) and 851 with [tag:cognitive-psychology]. Neuropsychology seems to makes use of (or share concepts with) neuroscience and cognitive psychology.
